# Should I dependency inject? How do I do it?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

Okay, so I am working with Microsoft Prism in WPF using a MVVMC(or MVCVM) pattern.

In my ChatModule I have a series of Views, ViewModels, and one Controller.

For the Views I have

- ChatAreaView - Displays the chat messages that come in to be read. This is hosted inside of a TabControl region so that I can have chat windows between the user and other users, or maybe file transfer windows, etc.
- UserAreaView - This is a list of the users. Right clicking has context menu to interact with them... like sending a file or whispering.
- MessageAreaView - This is where the user types in messages to be sent to all of the others.

For each view, I have a corresponding ViewModel. **ChatAreaViewModel, UserAreaViewModel and MessageAreaViewModel**. These ViewModels essentially only contain properties.

For example, the UserAreaViewModel defines a struct of type User which is essentially just a Name. Actually this is defined outside of the class, but still... it uses it. It has an ObservableCollection to store a list of all the Users who are currently connected. It also has ICommand properties defined to interact with the user. Right now I have SendFile, Whisper and Nudge... with intent on adding more in the future.

The Controller creates these views and ViewModels, and marriages them. It news them up, assigns the ViewModel as the corresponding View's DataContext, and sets all the initial properties of the ViewModel. Over the lifetime of the module, it will react to user interaction and execute DelegateCommands that it has assigned to each of the ViewModel's ICommand properties. These will further alter the state of the properties in a ViewModel.

I am using the actual types of Views and ViewModels, instead of interfaces, like such.

```
#region Views

ChatAreaView viewChatArea;
UserListView viewUserArea;
MessageView viewMessageArea;
LoginPromptView viewLoginPrompt;

#endregion

#region ViewModels

ChatAreaViewModel viewModelChatArea;
UserAreaViewModel viewModelUserArea;
MessageAreaViewModel viewModelMessageArea;
LoginPromptViewModel viewModelLoginPrompt;

#endregion
```

Would things be a lot more neat, less coupled if I defined interfaces for the Views and ViewModels, and operated on these interfaces within the controller instead of the concrete implementations? Could I then just register them with my Container in the Module class(which is essentially the root of each Module)?

What do I have to gain from doing this? How would I implement an interface for each view to distinguish them from the others? They don't really do ANYTHING except have XAML... and teh ViewModel's don't really do anything either except have certain properties. And those properties might be subject to change. On the UserAreaViewModel for instance, I will definitely want to add more commands so a user can interact with another user in different ways.

Can somebody help me out here? In my mind I'm thinking I should be abstracting this stuff, but I don't really know a logical way I should be going about it, or even if it's a wise idea to do so. What do I have to gain?

Thank you for your time. The below image is an example of what I'm working on. Ignore the Add new Item button and the styling of everything... that's not what I'm working on right now.

[image: Chat Application]

Answer (score 0):

1. loosely coupled - can replace an entire class with altogether different implementation in future.
2. independent development.. can inject a dummy UI / view until final UI gets ready. two pieces can evolve at the same time (after having a common contract).
3. no need to add references to the modules (implementing the view). can use ConfigurationModuleCatalog to discover types from config file.